# How FlurryAgent.onPageView() works?

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

I'm testing Flurry on a simple Android app that has just a single Activity.

I call the `FlurryAgent.onPageView();` from the Activity's `onCreate` method.

Is this the correct way to count page views?

Also, I can't find the PageView report on http://dev.flurry.com/, where is it?

Thanks,
Giacomo

Comment: You could post the answer here, because as is this page is useless

Answer (score 0):

first, you need call to `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(Context, String)`. Could be in `onStar()`. Then, after that, you can call to `FlurryAgent.onPageView();`. Just remember that the event `onCreate` is first that `onStar`

Answer (score 0):

According to the obfuscated code from FlurrySDK `.jar` file the only thing that `onPageView()` method do is increasing of static `int` page view counter. So i think @Litux is right about way of usage, BUT since this field is static i think it would'nt be a good idea to use it, for example, to count number of `Fragment` views, especcially if you  have several `Fragments` in one `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

As... *"Page View tracking is an optional part of the Flurry SDK that allows you to report the number of page views generated by your users for the purpose of tracking advertising. Since the definition of Page View differs for each application, the Flurry SDK cannot track these for you automatically. Instead, you need to add the appropriate integration points to track page views as they pertain to your application."*

If you want to log **specific** Page/**Activity/Fragment** usage and **User Paths**, you need to use custom events with `FlurryAgent.logEvent()`, optionally with `FlurryAgent.endTimedEvent()`.

You can integrate that in Activity/Fragment `onResume`, `onPause` callbacks.

Comment: I have the custom events, but the pageviews shows me the 0 as count. but my custom events are shown in my events section.